# Making use of Macros in sublime for regular expression matching

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following lines in sublime

```
 = "COLUMN"
 = "COLUMNS"
 = "COMBIN"
 = "COMPLEX"
 = "CONCAT"
```

I want to add what is inside of the double quotes to the begining of the line. Output will be

```
 COLUMN = "COLUMN"
 COLUMNS = "COLUMNS"
 COMBIN = "COMBIN"
 COMPLEX = "COMPLEX"
 CONCAT = "CONCAT"
```

The file is big with more than 1000 records. Can this be done with sublime macro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't require macros. Instead can be done with Sublime replace patterns

Choose Find -> Replace from the menu.

Enable regular expression by clicking **.*** button on the left hand side.

Find String:

```
^ = "([A-Z]+)"
```

Replace String

```
\1 = "\1"
```